# Most concise way to check existence of ALL files in a list (ArcPy)?

Tags: arcpy, layers, list

I'm running a process that includes generating a set of 3 curvature layers. For various reasons, sometimes I may generate just 1, 2, or all 3. Later I may need to go back and generate another layer, but the complication is that to create the first set of layers I used a randomly generated temporary surface. So if I were to create a sibling curvature layer, it wouldn't match the original. What I do, then, is to see if any of the 3 layers are missing. If so, I delete and recreate them all 3. But there must be a cleaner way.

```
curvLayers = [curvpath, profpath, planpath]
if (not arcpy.Exists(curvpath) or
  not arcpy.Exists(profpath) or
  not arcpy.Exists(planpath)):
    for layer in curvLayers:
        if arcpy.Exists(layer): DM.Delete(layer)
        <create new layers>
```

I'd love to think there was something like:

```
if not all arcpy.Exists(curvLayers):
```

Comment: You can try `any` function of Python with a list comprehension with `Exists`.

Comment: So, `if any(arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers):`? But I need to test for 'all', not 'any'.

Comment: Perhaps set arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True.  Then just run the tools and allow them to overwrite existing files if they find.  Although it will not work for certain tools.

Comment: Your original conditional, `(not arcpy.Exists(curvpath) or not arcpy.Exists(profpath) or not arcpy.Exists(planpath))`, can be translated into `any` context (because all conditional connectors are `or`) as `if any(not arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers)`.

Comment: Interesting: putting `not` within the parentheses provides yet another permutation. Thanks for clarifying; I wasn't picking up on that from your first comment. I'll reference this in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `all()` function does the trick. The code above can be condensed as follows:

```
curvLayers = [curvpath, profpath, planpath]
if not all(arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers): #"If any files missing..."
    for layer in curvLayers:
        if arcpy.Exists(layer): DM.Delete(layer)
        <create new layers>
```

The first `if` clause above evaluates to `True` if one or more are missing, and `False` if all files exist.

---

Note I'm using `not` to manipulate the logic of the `all()` function, which flips the result. Alternate examples, for clarity:

```
if all(arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers): #"If all files exist..."
```

or...

```
if any(arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers): #"If any files exist..."
```

or...

```
if not any(arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers): #"If all files missing..."
```

Alternatively, I suppose I could use the `else` clause instead of the `not` to flip the result, but using `not` makes the code more readable.
Thanks @fatih_dur for getting me so close to the solution.

EDIT: As @fatih_dur points out up top, yet another variation in the logic (putting `not` inside the function) can accomplish the same thing:

```
if any(not arcpy.Exists(c) for c in curvLayers): #"If any files missing..."
```

I'll refrain from building this variation into all the other options, as it would undermine my efforts at clarity!